# Java exit() method hungs after loop creation in a linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

Trying to create loop within a linked list, program is as below. But once the method is done making the loop, java exit() thread gets called and it gets hung there. I dont understand what could be the issue here.

```
package Inter;

import Inter.LinkedList.node;

public class LinkedListLoops {



    public static void makeLoop(node nod)
    {

        node cur = nod;
        while(cur.next!=null)
            cur= cur.next;
        cur.next=nod.next;

    }

    public static void main(String argsp[])
    {
        LinkedList l1 = new LinkedList();
        l1.addNode(1);
        l1.addNode(2);
        l1.addNode(3);
        l1.addNode(4);
        l1.addNode(5);
        LinkedListLoops.makeLoop(l1.head);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you closely look at your code

```
while(cur.next!=null)
        cur= cur.next;
    cur.next=nod.next;
```

That means

```
while(cur.next!=null){
        cur= cur.next;
}
    cur.next=nod.next;
```

Which gone infinite. That is the reason you need to have curly braces when you are a beginner :)

You have to write

```
while(cur.next!=null){
    cur= cur.next;
    cur.next=nod.next;
}
```